# R For loop works fine in R Studio, not in VS Code

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, r-markdown, rstudio

When I write a for loop in VS Code in which the braces are in a separate line I get an error.

```
vars <- c("line1", "line2", "line3")

for (var in vars){
  print("a")
  print(var)
}
```

What shows up in the terminal however is slightly different. It seems that VS Code only considers the first `print` as part of the loop.

[image]

The same works fine in R Studio:

[image]

Can anyone help?

**Edit:** Fiddling around, I've realized that the problem does not occur when the said code is executed via an R script. Only in rmd files.

Comment: In the first code example you have a `}` right after the 1st `print`. You are closing `}` twice. Note that `"line3"` is printed because it executes outside the `for` loop, when `var` takes that value.

Comment: Works for me. You appear to be running this funkyly.

Comment: This is probably a typo, VTC.

Comment: @RuiBarradas No, as I explain that is what shows up in the VS Code terminal. If you read the text (not the image) then it has no } after the first print.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Still the same for me. I simply press the 'Run Chunk' button that appears above the code segment.

Comment: I have also discovered that this problem does not occur when I use an R script. Only the in R Markdown file.

Comment: Then copy/paste the code chunk. Generally, *`unexpected '}' in "}"`* is how a syntax error would show up.

Comment: @GregorThomas That is how I did it. It seems that VS Code was/is executing lines separately. The same file works fine in R Studio. I'm probably going to do a clean install on VS Code.